# Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function array-callback-return on filter function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, arrow-functions

I'm working in React and I'm currently getting the error "Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return". I've searched other questions, but can't seem to find one that matches min (unless I'm totally blind). I have the following code.

```js
const self = this;
const relevantCompanyMeasures = this.props.companyMeasures
  .filter(companyMeasure => {
    for(const measure of self.state.measures) {
      if(measure.id === companyMeasure.measure_type_id) return true;
      else return false;
    }
  });
```

The code loops through two arrays of objects looking for a match between the two. If I had only returned true for matches, I would have understood the error. However, I return false in the case that there is no match. As a result, I'm struggling to see how I'd end up in a situation where there is no return value at the end of the arrow function.

Comment: filter method only return on arrayOfValue if condition satisfied..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because the `return` only exits the `for` loop, and not the entire callback in `Array.prototype.filter()`. Instead of using for loop to check if `companyMeasure.measure_type_id` exists in `self.state.measures`, you can simply do an [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which returns all the IDs, and then check against that return array if the ID exists using [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
const self = this;
const relevantCompanyMeasures = this.props.companyMeasures
  .filter(companyMeasure => {
    return self.state.measures.map(m => m.id).includes(companyMeasure.measure_type_id);
  });
```

Even better:

- since you are using arrow functions, the lexical `this` from the enclosing scope is preserved, so you don't even need to proxy `this` at all
- you can also create the array map outside the `.filter()` callback to reduce overhead
- now the `.filter()` callback is a one-liner, we can get rid of the curly brackets and [take advantage of implicit returns in arrow functions](https://jaketrent.com/post/javascript-arrow-function-return-rules/)

Here's how the final code should look like:

```
const ids = this.state.measures.map(m => m.id);
const relevantCompanyMeasures = this.props.companyMeasures
  .filter(companyMeasure => id.includes(companyMeasure.measure_type_id));
```

Comment: @user48003 No problem! Everybody starts somewhere ;) glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. The loop starts
2. You get the first `measure`
3. The condition is true and you return true
4. You never advance to the second `measure`

Or:

1. The loop starts
2. You get the first `measure`
3. The condition is false and you return false
4. You never advance to the second `measure`

---

Get rid of the `else` and move the `return false` to *after* the loop so it only runs if you get to the end of the loop without finding a match.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const self = this;
const relevantCompanyMeasures = this.props.companyMeasures
  .filter(companyMeasure => {
             return self.state.measures.map(meas => meas.id).indexOf(companyMeasure.measure_type_id)!=-1
    }
   );
```

Try this