# How to fix "Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function"

Tags: reactjs

I'm having some issues understanding why I'm getting a warning on this piece of my React code

> Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function

but it seems to work.

```
 {customers
    .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
    .filter((customer) => {
      if (searchTerm === "") {
        return customer;
      } else if (
        customer.cust_main_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        return customer;
      }
    })
```

What changes do I need to implement to avoid this warning?

Comment: You have `if/else if` without a final `else`. That means if neither condition matches, the function won't have a return at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fix "Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014094/how-do-i-fix-expected-to-return-a-value-at-the-end-of-arrow-function-warning)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function array-callback-return on filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880841/expected-to-return-a-value-at-the-end-of-arrow-function-array-callback-return-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` expects a value to be returned from within the callback function implying whether to keep or rejeect the current itemm value

However in your callback function you have if-else-if block where you return thee value but it none of the if or else-if conditions match, you don't return anything which what the error points

You can **return false** if none of your if or else-if condition matches

```
customers
    .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
    .filter((customer) => {
      if (searchTerm === "") {
        return customer;
      } else if (
        customer.cust_main_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
      ) {
        return customer;
      }
      return false;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

a more compact version:

```
{customers
    .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
    .filter((customer) => !searchTerm || customer.cust_main_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) 
    })
```